# Angular 14 strictly typed reactive forms - How to type FormGroup model using existing interface

Tags: angular, strong-typing, angular14

I'm just playing around with new angular typed forms api and couldn't figure out how to type `FormGroup` without declaring specific "FormInterface" witch has to match the original one.

Maybe I'm missing something or it's just impossible to do so.

I was able to make thing working correctly (example below), but what I'm not a fan of here is declaration of `UserForm` interface witch has no reference to `User` interface and has to be a mirror copy of it but with `FormControl<>` fields.

Is it possible in case like this to type `FormGroup` just with `User` interface?.

Full working example available on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zkxz54)

**user.model.ts**

```
export interface User {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  email: string;
  age: number | null;
}
```

**user.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  add(user: User): void {
    console.log('Add user', user);
  }

}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
interface UserForm {
  firstName: FormControl<string>;
  lastName: FormControl<string>;
  email: FormControl<string>;
  age: FormControl<number | null>;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  form: FormGroup<UserForm>;

  constructor(private userService: UserService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      firstName: new FormControl<string>('', { nonNullable: true }),
      lastName: new FormControl('', { nonNullable: true }),
      email: new FormControl('', { nonNullable: true }),
      age: new FormControl<number | null>(null),
    });
  }

  submitForm(): void {
    this.userService.add(this.form.getRawValue());
  }
}
```

Comment: We hear you on the Angular team. We're considering ways to reduce the amount of boilerplate in future Angular versions. For now, you do have to declare a separate interface that uses controls. Another option would be to instantiate the `FormGroup` at the declaration site, instead of the constructor, and rely on type inference to deduce the type automatically.

Answer (score 36):

I also ran into this because I always assign my `FormGroup` later and I was not happy about having to add a ton of boilerplate types on every `FormGroup` declaration. It felt like I was repeating myself, so what I ended up doing was creating a utility type which has been working well.

```js
export type ModelFormGroup<T> = FormGroup<{
  [K in keyof T]: FormControl<T[K]>;
}>;
```

This makes it easy to type the `FormGroup` declarations for the many data models I have. For example:

```js
export interface UserModel {
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

// In a class...
userFormGroup: ModelFormGroup<UserModel>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.userFormGroup = this._formBuilder.nonNullable.group({
    email: [''],
    password: [''],
  });
}
```

Many times my data models will have more properties than I want the form to
have, so I take advantage of [TypeScript's utility types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html) `Pick`, `Required`, `Omit`, etc...

```js
export interface UserModel {
  email: string;
  password: string;
  dateAdded: Date;
  dateUpdated: Date;
}

// In a class...
userFormGroup: ModelFormGroup<Pick<UserModel, 'email' | 'password' >>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.userFormGroup = this._formBuilder.nonNullable.group({
    email: [''],
    password: [''],
  });
}
```

Comment: for me this solution throws an error when I try to emit the value on submit:

"Argument of type 'Partial<{ username: string; password: string; }>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UserModel'.
  Types of property 'username' are incompatible.
    Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'. 
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'. "

Comment: @balintd This solution has nothing to do with what you're seeing. A `FormGroup` **always** returns a `Partial` bc form controls can be potentially disabled and therefore return `undefined`. Check [docs here.](https://angular.io/guide/typed-forms#partial-values) If you want to access the value including disabled controls, and thus bypass possible undefined fields, you can use `.getRawValue()`.

Comment: Thanks for clarification!
Based on this, using the types seems to be pointless to me, since cannot use the interface properly after the form submission:
@Output() readonly submit: EventEmitter<UserModel> = new EventEmitter<UserModel>();
  form!: FormGroupModel<UserModel>;

Comment: Fantastic! This helped me fix the issue and understand Typescript further.

Comment: If you change ModelFormGroup a little, you can add support for FormArray as well.

`type Unbox<T> = T extends Array<infer V> ? V : T;`

`export type ModelFormGroup<T> = FormGroup<{
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends Array<any>
    ? FormArray<FormControl<Unbox<T[K]>>> 
    : FormControl<T[K]>;
}>;`

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend defining your FormGroup and inferring the `User` interface from it. Use the following utility types to help you.

```
export type FormValue<T extends AbstractControl> = T extends AbstractControl<infer TValue, any> ? TValue : never;
export type FormRawValue<T extends AbstractControl> = T extends AbstractControl<any, infer TRawValue> ? TRawValue : never;
```

Note that the `FormValue` type will make all the properties optional, because the controls can be disabled. If you don't disable controls or mark disable-able controls optional yourself, the `FormRawValue` type will help you more. In your case, use the latter.

```
interface UserFormControls {
  firstName: FormControl<string>;
  lastName: FormControl<string>;
  email: FormControl<string>;
  age: FormControl<number | null>;
}

export type UserForm = FormGroup<UserFormControls>;

export type User = FormRawValue<UserForm>;
// type User = {
//  firstName: string;
//  lastName: string;
//  email: string;
//  age: number | null;
// }
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2shncq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fuser.model.ts)

Answer (score 3):

I have a solution for this problem i'm wrote some types for that https://github.com/iamguid/ngx-mf .

For example you can do something like that:

We define some model:

```js
enum ContactType {
    Email,
    Telephone,
}

interface IContactModel {
    type: ContactType;
    contact: string;
}

interface IUserModel {
    id: number;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    nickname: string;
    birthday: Date;
    contacts: IContactModel[];
}
```

Then we define some magic type like:

```js
Type Form = FormModel<IUserModel, { contacts: ['group'] }>
```

Then we have type based on our model before form will be init:

```js
FormGroup<{
    firstName: FormControl<string | null>;
    lastName: FormControl<string | null>;
    nickname: FormControl<string | null>;
    birthday: FormControl<Date | null>;
    contacts: FormArray<FormGroup<{
        type: FormControl<ContactType | null>;
        contact: FormControl<string | null>;
    }>>;
}>
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @RcoderNY's answer, you can also create a mapped type for `FormBuilder` similarly by using [ControlConfig](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlConfig):

```
export type ControlConfigMap<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: ControlConfig<T[K]>
};
```

Then, you can use it like this:

```
export interface UserModel {
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

// In a class...
userFormGroup: ModelFormGroup<UserModel>;

ngOnInit() {
  this.userFormGroup = this._formBuilder.nonNullable.group<ControlConfigMap<UserModel>>({
    email: ['', Validators.required],
    password: ['', Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)] // error: third element in tuple should be of type AsyncValidatorFn or AsyncValidatorFn[]
  });
}
```

Note that `ControlConfig` was exposed in version [14.0.6](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/HEAD/CHANGELOG.md#forms-4). Earlier versions will throw an error when using this type.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a definite assignment to your form variable. Below is the code:

```
form!: FormGroup;
```

You can also use your declaration to initialize the form controls since you're 'posting' values on the form and not yet updating.

```
form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
      firstName: new FormControl<string>('', { nonNullable: true }),
      lastName: new FormControl('', { nonNullable: true }),
      email: new FormControl('', { nonNullable: true }),
      age: new FormControl<number | null>(null),
    });
```

Comment: You're right, except for the part where you say an interface is taxing in resources. They are removed completely when transpiled down to JS, so they take up no space at all.

Comment: Declaraing `form: FormGroup` will prevent the type from being inferred, since you declared the type to be just `FormGroup` with no type parameter. You should use type inference instead, and not specify `: FormGroup`.

Comment: Use `NonNullableFormBuilder` so you don't have to specify `{nonNullable:true}` a million times

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `User` as the type of `FormGroup`.
You can however reference `User` in `UserForm` with `enums` then use `UserForm` as a type of `FormGroup`. Check out [#72500855](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72500855/formbuilder-with-strongly-typed-form-in-ng14) on strongly typed forms with `Angular 14` since your question is a potential duplicate of it.

Answer (score 0):

What works fairly well is using type interference with the `FormBuilder`.

```js
const form = this.formBuilder.group<User>({ /* your form definition */ });
```

This will create a type-safe form that interferes the controls and their types from the `User` interface.

E.g.

```js
form.patchValue({ age: "15" }); // shows error because `age` has to be a number
form.patchValue({ password: "myPassword"}); // shows error because `password` does not exist on `User` interface.
```

What is missing though is an easy type definition of the `FormGroup` class, e.g. when the assignment with the `FormBuilder` only happens later. The type definition that Angular uses in the `FormBuilder.create` is

```js
group<T extends {}>(...): FormGroup<{[K in keyof T]: ɵElement<T[K], null>}>
```

Which is not something I want to have in my code but maybe a simple helper type can already solve this problem.

```js
export type MyFormGroup<T> = FormGroup<{[K in keyof T]: ɵElement<T[K], null>;}>;
const myForm: MyFormGroup<User>;
// `myForm` will now have the same type as the previously shown from the `FormBuilder.group` call.
```