# How can I restrict the value type of FormGroup in ts?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, types, typechecking

I have a const like this:

```
const defaultInfo: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
  id: 1,
  name: qian,
  amount: 123,
})
```

and I want to restrict the type inside the FormGroup, so I write like this:

```
interface InfoInterface {
  id: number,
  name: string,
  amount: number,
}


interface InfoFormGroup extends FormGroup {
  value: InfoInterface
}

const defaultInfo: InfoFormGroup = this.fb.group({
  id: 1,
  name: qian,
  amount: 123,
})
```

obviously it doesn't work, because whatever I change the properties of Info Interface to, there is no error, why? how can I restrict the value type of FormGroup in ts

restrict the value type of FormGroup in ts

Comment: I'm not that familiar with TypeScript, but I'll assume you want to narrow down the `FormGroup` type. This can be done by using a type intersection. `const defaultInfo: FormGroup & { value: InfoInterface } = this...` don't know if this works, but it might point you in the right direction.

Comment: I've tried this way, but it didn't work,I'm not sure if it because I can't use the value properties, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I think it should help you: https://angular.io/guide/typed-forms

Basically you need to make your interface have form controls instead of normal types:

```
  interface InfoInterface {
      id: FormControl<number>,
      name: FormControl<string>,
      amount: FormControl<number>
  }
    
  const info = new FormGroup<InfoInterface>({
      id: new FormControl(0),
      name: new FormControl(''),
      amount: new FormControl(0)
  });
```

keep in mind that it was introduced in angular 14, so it will not work in previous versions

Comment: thanks a lot, it works, and I check the link, angular didn't provide a way to do the same in FormBuilder, that means I can't restrict the types if I'm using FormBuilder to create new instances

Comment: For FormBuilder I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72500855/formbuilder-with-strongly-typed-form-in-ng14